# Why can't the rank of a linear map be greater than the dimension of the domain?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In my introductory linear algebra course, I have come across the rank-nullity theorem, namely:

$$\dim(Im(f)) + \dim(\ker(f)) = \dim(V) $$

Where $f : V \to W$ is a linear map. From this equation, the dimension of the kernel of $f$ can be no smaller than $0$ ($0$ if and only if the kernel only contains the zero vector and all vector spaces by definition contain the zero vector). This means that  $\dim(Im(f))$, the dimension of the image of $f$ is at most equal to $dim(V)$, the dimension of the domain.

From a purely equational standpoint, this makes sense to me, but I was wondering if anybody could provide an intuitive explanation as to why the rank cannot exceed the dimension of the domain.

Thank you.

Comment: Because the preimages of a set of linearly independent vectors must be linearly independent.

Comment: @user51547 Thank you that makes sense

Comment: Because the image of a basis of V spans Image(f).

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks, I overlooked this simple fact